# Angular directive to close a modal with the escape key

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've created an Angular directive that is supposed to close a modal when the escape key is pressed. The modal service works just fine when used within controllers, but for some reason it doesn't work within this directive. The following code will print `hello` when escape is pressed but it will not hide the modal. Any ideas?

**DIRECTIVE**

```
app.directive("dpEscape", function(modal) {
  return function(scope, element, attributes) {
    element.on("keyup", function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode == 27) {
        console.log("hello");
        modal.hide();
      }
    });
  };
});
```

I don't actually think any of the following code is relevant to the problem, but I could be wrong. Since I know people are going to ask for it anyways, here it is:

**HTML**

```
...
<html ng-app="trread" ng-controller="Main" dp-escape>
...
```

**SERVICE**

```
app.factory("modal", function() {

  var urlPath = "/templates/modals/";
  var visible = false;
  var templateUrl = "";
  var content = {};
  var controller = {};
  var size = {width: 500, height: 500};

  var show = function() {
    visible = true;
  }

  var hide = function() {
    visible = false;
  }

  var setTemplate = function(url) {
    templateUrl = urlPath + url + ".html";
  }

  var getTemplate = function() {
    return templateUrl;
  }

  var setContent = function(contentObj) {
    content = contentObj;
  }

  var getContent = function() {
    return content;
  }

  var setController = function(controllerObj) {
    controller = controllerObj;
  }

  var getController = function() {
    return controller;
  }

  var isVisible = function() {
    return visible;
  }

  return {
    show: show,
    hide: hide,
    setTemplate: setTemplate,
    getTemplate: getTemplate,
    setContent: setContent,
    getContent: getContent,
    setController: setController,
    getController: getController,
    isVisible: isVisible,
  };

});
```

Comment: Not so sure reading this code, but try to wrap the if (on the directive) in a `scope.$apply()`

Comment: Good, I added a proper response then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since classic events like `click`, `keydown`, etc are not managed by `Angular` but by the browser. If you modify your `$scope` inside of one of those events, you need to tell `Angular` that something have happened outside is context. That is the `$apply`. With `$apply` you can run things outside `Angular context` and make `Angular` aware when needed.